# How can I check if a class has been instantiated in Python ?

Tags: python-3.x

In one of my classes, I am printing data from another class that is yet to be initialized.I only want to print that data once the class has been initialized.Is there any way check if the class has been instantiated?

Comment: Can't you just use `isinstance` ?

Comment: Something like `if isinstance(instance, MyObject): ...` ?

Comment: I am not creating any objects of that class.I am just using that class to process some data.In my main program, I want to print that data.However, that class gets initialized only after the first run of the program.So, it needs at least one run to get initialized.That's where my code is failing.Pardon me if it sounds stupid,i am new to python3.

Comment: Usually data should live in an instance. If you're storing it as a class variable, you're going to have problems. It makes more sense for the class that consumes the data to be passed an instance of the class that calculates the data than for it to go seek out the information in some ambiguous way.

Comment: is there a way to check if a class has been initialized rather than checking for instances of a class?

Comment: Classes in Python don't automatically keep track of their instances (or even whether there are any or not). If you want such behavior, you need to write it yourself. Try having your class's `__init__` or `__new__` method update a class variable or something.

Answer (score 12):

Two functions that return true if you pass an undeclared class, and false if it is instantiated:

```
import inspect
inspect.isclass(myclass)
```

or

```
isinstance(myclass, type)
```

In general, if it's not a type (i.e. undeclared class), it's an instantiated type.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a variable into the class to be made, like this:

```
class tobeinitiated():
    initiated=False
    def __init__(self):
        global initiated
        tobeinitiated.initiated = True
```

Then, where you need the information:

```
global initiated #(if in class)
if tobeinitiated.initiated:
    #do the stuff you need to do
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thank you for helping, but unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: spider = HeadlessSpider(CONFIG, HOMEPAGE, DOMAIN_NAME)
  File "/Users/mayank/web-scrape-poc/spiders/headless_spider.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.crawl_page('First spider', (Spider.base_url, 0))
  File "/Users/mayank/web-scrape-poc/spiders/headless_spider.py", line 33, in crawl_page
    super().crawl_page(thread_name, page_url)
  File "/Users/mayank/web-scrape-poc/spiders/spider.py", line 63, in crawl_page
    ' | Broken Images : ',ImageChecker.count if ImageChecker.instantiate else 0)
NameError: name 'ImageChecker' is not defined

Comment: Those `global` statements don't make any sense. If you're assigning to a class variable, you're not assigning to a global. Either could work, but just pick one.

Comment: Manyank Gupta it seems that you have named the variable and referenced it as something else

Answer (score -1):

You can add a counter of instances in the constructor for example.